# JPA @Lob annotation can not be handled by Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with my JPA application accessing a @Lob attribute when using [hibernate](https://hibernate.org/).

The attribute in my JPA entity class looks like this:

```java
    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Map<String, List<Object>> getData() {
        return data;
    }
```

When I used [eclipselink](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) as the JPA implementation and a PostgreSQL Database, my 'data' column get the type `bytea` which is fine.

But if I change the JPA implementation from eclipselink to hibernate (actually, I switch from Payara to Wildfly), hibernate has a problem to access this column. I see exceptions like this one:

```
app_1  |    at org.postgresql@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toLong(PgResultSet.java:2873)
app_1  |    at org.postgresql@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2099)
app_1  |    at org.postgresql@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getBlob(PgResultSet.java:419)
app_1  |    at org.postgresql@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getBlob(PgResultSet.java:406)
app_1  |    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getBlob(WrappedResultSet.java:781)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$1.doExtract(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:48)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3026)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1844)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1772)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1745)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1598)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:742)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1002)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:960)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351)
app_1  |    at org.hibernate@5.3.23.Final//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2787)
....
.......
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
.....
```

I guess I have to tell hibernate how to map my `@Lob` column. But I don't want a solution where I have to add hibernate code into my entity class as I want to get my code working on different JPA implementation.
Is it possible to solve this issue using some custom properties in the persistence.xml file or using a custom hibernate configuration file?

Comment: I've never used eclipselink, but in hibernate `@Lob` fields need to be of certain types as far I know (check the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-blob-example)). I wonder if eclipselink serialises the object (`Map` in this case) into the column, which could be a nightmare if the object changes later as.

Comment: But can I describe my preferred column mapping for one table with some hibernate config file?

Comment: do you mean using `@Table` or `@Coulmn` annotations? check this:
https://www.journaldev.com/17803/jpa-hibernate-annotations

Comment: You can't map the Lob to `Map<String, List<Object>>` What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you want the `Map` to be stored in a different table, you can use the [`@CollectionTable`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-map) annotation.

Comment: The @lob annotation is noting exotic. It is up to the JPA implementation to map the field or property to a Blob data table column. Eclipselink uses the type `bytea` and hibernate a `oid`. I want to figure out how to tell Hibernate to switch from `oid` to `bytea` (as I already have data in my table).

Comment: It looks like for hibernate you have to write your own custom mapper class to map `java.sql.Blob` into a custom Serializable Java object. This is surprising, as Eclipselink supports this feature out of the box.